# Android Room Relationships -- List of Foreign Keys

Tags: android, android-room

I'm having trouble understanding how to set up my Room relationships. I haven't found an example analogous to mine anywhere online.

I have a User object (I've left out getters and setters):

```
@Entity
public class User {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private String userId;

@ColumnInfo
private String name;

@ColumnInfo
private List<Long> seminarsAttended;
}
```

and a Seminar object:

```
@Entity
public class Seminar {

@PrimaryKey
private Long seminarId;

@ColumnInfo
private String topic;
....}
```

The list "seminarsAttended" in the User object is a list of seminarIds. The User class is linked up to a Retrofit call, so I can't modify the class to instead hold a list of Seminar objects.

How can I model this relationship in Room, such that the seminarIds in the User's seminarsAttended list are correlated with their corresponding Seminar in the seminars.db table?

It looks like the list of seminarsAttended should be a list of foreign keys into the seminars.db table, but I'm having trouble finding an example.